# Dynamically executing delegates

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, delegates

I have a class which is basically a message handler, it accepts requests, finds a processor for that message type, creates an appropriate response and returns it.  To this end, I have 
created a delegate as follows `public delegate Rs ProcessRequest<Rq,Rs>(Rq request);` and then inside my class, created a number of supported messages and their process methods.  The problem is the main process method which should figure out which process method to use can't find the method using the GetMethod() method.

Here is the whole code, if you could tell me how to dynamically select the appropriate method and then execute it, thats pretty much what I am looking for.

```
public delegate Rs ProcessRequest<in Rq, out Rs>(Rq request) where Rq : API.Request where Rs : API.Response;

public class WebSocketServer
{
    private WebSocketMessageHandler messageHander;

    // Incoming message handlers
    public ProcessRequest<InitUDPConnectionRq, InitUDPConnectionRs> ProcessInitUDPConnection;
    public ProcessRequest<ListenHandshakeRq, ListenHandshakeRs> ProcessListenHandshake;
    public ProcessRequest<PresenceChangeRq, PresenceChangeRs> ProcessPresenceChange;
    public ProcessRequest<ChatMessageRq, ChatMessageRs> ProcessChatMessage;
    public ProcessRequest<RDPRequestResponseRq, RDPRequestResponseRs> ProcessRDPRequestResponse;
    public ProcessRequest<RDPIncomingRequestRq, RDPIncomingRequestRs> ProcessRDPIncomingRequest;

    public WebSocketServer(WebSocketMessageHandler handler)
    {
        this.messageHander = handler;
    }

    public void processRequest(API.Request request)
    {
        String resquestType = request.GetType().Name;
        String processorName = resquestType.Substring(0, resquestType.Length - 2);
        API.Response response = null;
        // Do we have a process method for this processor
        MethodInfo methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("Process" + processorName);
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
             // Execute the method via Invoke...., but code never gets here
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Warn("Failed to find a processor for " + processorName);
            response = new ErrorRs(request.id, "Failed to find a processor for " + processorName);
        }
        sendResponse(response, request);
    }
}
```

Now I assign those fields to methods as I go, I just can't dynamically execute them.

```
// Link into the hooks so we can receive requests
_appContext.ConnectionManager.Connection.webSocketServer.ProcessInitUDPConnection = ProcessInitUDPConnection;
_appContext.ConnectionManager.Connection.webSocketServer.ProcessListenHandshake = ProcessListenHandshake;
_appContext.ConnectionManager.Connection.webSocketServer.ProcessPresenceChange = ProcessPresenceChange;
_appContext.ConnectionManager.Connection.webSocketServer.ProcessChatMessage = ProcessChatMessage;

// 1 method as an example
private PresenceChangeRs ProcessPresenceChange(PresenceChangeRq request)
{
    _appContext.RosterManager.presenceChange(request.user, request.presence);
    return new PresenceChangeRs();
}
```

Comment: Why not use an explicit `Dictionary<string, ProcessRequest<...>>` instead of reflection? Should be easier to tell what went wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `this.GetType().GetField("Process" + processorName);` instead of `GetMethod`?

Comment: fair enough, but how would I dynamically execute that after I retrieve it from the dictionary, can you perhaps show me some code?

Comment: Chris : I tried this and I get it out, the question is, how do I execute it?  I tried InvokeMember with no success, perhaps I just don't know how

Comment: Assuming dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, System.Delegate>`: `System.Delegate myDelegate = Dictionary["Process" + processorName]; myDelegate.DynamicInvoke(request);` You lose type-safety, but that's the simplest way.

Comment: Regarding the `GetField()`: `Delegate process = (Delegate)this.GetType().GetField("Process" + requestType).GetValue(this); process.DynamicInvoke(.....`

Comment: Chris : Thanks for that code, I do like the Dictionary idea, could you tell me how to get it into the dictionary, as in a method which takes in the processor name, the request type and response type and creates a delegate so I can put it in the dictionary?  that would be most helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample code for the `Dictionary` usage. Bit too many custom types for me to make sure it compiles fully and tested, but should get you on the right track.

```
public class WebSocketServer
{
    private WebSocketMessageHandler messageHander;

    // Incoming message handlers
    private Dictionary<string, System.Delegate> ProcessHandlers = new Dictionary<string, System.Delegate>();

    public void RegisterProcessHandler(string name, System.Delegate handler)
    {
        ProcessHandlers.Add(name, handler);
    }

    public void processRequest(API.Request request)
    {
        String resquestType = request.GetType().Name;
        String processorName = resquestType.Substring(0, resquestType.Length - 2);
        API.Response response = null;

        string processorName = "Process" + processorName;

        if (ProcessHandlers.ContainsKey(processorName))
        {
            System.Delegate myDelegate = ProcessHandlers[processorName]; 
            response = (API.Response)myDelegate.DynamicInvoke(request);
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Warn("Failed to find a processor for " + processorName);
            response = new ErrorRs(request.id, "Failed to find a processor for " + processorName);
        }

        sendResponse(response, request);
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
var webSocketServer = _appContext.ConnectionManager.Connection.webSocketServer;
webSocketServer.RegisterProcessHandler("InitUDPConnection", ProcessInitUDPConnection);
webSocketServer.RegisterProcessHandler("ListenHandshake", ProcessListenHandshake);
```

Comment: This was exactly right, thanks Chris, I only had 1 thing left to do really and that is cast my methods to (ProcessRequest<SpecificRq,SpecificRs>)processMethod for RegisterProcessHandler. Outstanding!